# Remove index.php from basic auth request on php-cgi

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, kohana-3

I have a Kohana 3.3 application, and I have removed `/index.php/` from the URI with some rules in an .htaccess file. Everything is working fine, until I come to use Basic Authentication. I can’t access Basic Auth from `$_SERVER` because the site is served with php-cgi, [which is explained here](http://community.webfaction.com/questions/7249/is-possible-http-authentication-with-php).

The solution in the previous link works, though it adds `/index.php/` back into the URI. I can’t seem to manage to add the new rewrite rule without the server throwing a 500.

Here are my current rewrite rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
# Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
#  RewriteBase /
</IfModule>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
#RewriteRule .* app/index.php/$0 [PT]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$0 [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^$ index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

And here’s what  I need to add:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^Basic.*
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?Authorization=%{HTTP:Authorization} [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

How can I make this work? And is there a relatively easy way to learn how mod_rewrite works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /api/

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b /index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$0 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^Basic.*
RewriteRule ^ index.php?Authorization=%{HTTP:Authorization} [L]
```

Comment: Seems to not be working. I still need `index.php` in the URI for this code to work.

Comment: Are you still getting 500 or that is gone? Can you give me an exampls URL that requires you to have `index.php`

Comment: Your code doesn’t produce a 500, but it does produce a 404. If I remove the forward-slash from your last rewrite rule, then I can access domain.com/api/index.php/users/1, but if possible I’d like to use domain.com/api/users/1.

Comment: Have you placed this code in `/api/` folder OR in `DocumentRoot`?

Comment: The .htaccess folder is in the /api directory.